# Texpad not compiling bibliography; same project new computer

Tags: bibtex, mac, texpad

I was happily working on a paper in Texpad for a few weeks without issue. But I bought a new computer and now am no longer happily working on said paper. When I try to compile the paper on the new machine, the bibliography does not generate. I have tried switching the bibliography engine, but to no avail. There is no problem with my .bib file, as it works just fine on overleaf and on my old mac that runs Texpad.

Any thoughts on what to do?

[image: Screenshot of what happens]

Comment: you need to give some clues:  what does "does not compile" mean? do you mean bibtex is not run, or that it does run but does not generate a bibliography, or are you using biber not bibtex? what errors are in the tex log or bibtex log?

Comment: Edited the post to better reflect my situation. When I typset the document, it does not generate a bibliography. In Texpad there's an option to use biber, bibtex, and some others but none of them work either. Hope this helps

Comment: sorry it is nowhere near enough information for me to guess anything (but I don't have texpad so I would not be the best person to guess, perhaps someone will be able to answer)  Even after the edit I can not tell if bibtex ran but failed o generate a bibliography or if it did not run at all. You can't "swich bibliography engine" via a menu (well you can but it can not work tha way) the markup in thelatex document eiher uses biblatex and requires biber, or uses biblatex and declares legacy bibtex processing or uses classic bibtex commands. But you have given no hint about your tex document.

Comment: as you show a cite key rather than `??` I would guess that you are using biblatex and so need to run biber and thn run latex again, but can only guess.